# Hyper extended right shoulder and swelling and sever swelling in back muscles

Tags: dogs, injury

I got a call from my neighbor saying he found my dog in the creek and she wasn't moving her back legs. I rushed from work to get her. I took her to the vet and he said that she had a hyper-extended right front arm and severe swelling in the large muscle in the middle of her back. She has deep tissue pain and her spine is still intact. She tries to move, but it's obviously very painful.

The vet gave me 3 medicines to give her and told me to call him at noon today. My question is **what is the best way to move her without causing any pain to her or more injury?**

I'm having to care for her at home, because I can't afford to keep her at the Animal Hospital. When I move her, she doesn't seem to be too bothered. You can tell it's sensitive, but she doesn't yelp with pain or anything. She tries to stand on her own, but when she does, the pain does make her whimper a little bit.

I'm trying to keep her as still as possible and I have a heating pad set on low to her back. I got her laying on a dog pillow with the puppy pad under.  She's eating and drinking water and seems content for the moment. Any suggestions on moving her would help. Also, the medicines he gave her are methocarbomal, prednisone, and tramadol. They are in low doses, so she stays coherent.

Comment: Didn't the vet give you directions for treatment of the injury? Why would you trust random internet people over competent medical professionals? (It's one thing to ask for advice prior to a vet's visit, but you've already done that and they are most familiar with your pet's recovery now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend having the dog blanket moved with her on it. Slide it slowly and hopefully it wont cause pain.

Comment: Thank you James that made it  easy to turn her over without stressing her out. Also after that suggestion I found a cool vet page that gave some Less invasive therapy ideas with sheets. So thank you.